# Ordering Issue with Array When Using WHERE and IN in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting

I have a simple mysql query like this.
SELECT name,cat_id FROM table WHERE cat_id IN (67,65,66);

But I am having a problem getting the results back in a proper order.

```
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cat_name] => name 1

            [cat_id] => 65
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [cat_name] => name 2
            [cat_id] => 66
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [cat_name] => name 3
            [cat_id] => 67
        )
```

I need them to be ordered by the cat_id that was put into the sql statement.

67, then 65 and then 66.

But it always wants to return results by order 65, 66, 67.

Can someone help me figure this out?  I rather get the results in the correct order, than use php to manipulate the array.

Comment: treid to add `ORDER BY cat_id DESC`?

Comment: ORDER BY FIELD(67,65,66) [DESC]

Comment: The RDBMS-agnostic way is `ORDER BY CASE cat_id WHEN 67 THEN 0 WHEN 65 THEN 1 WHEN 66 THEN 2 END`.

Comment: This worked but I don't really want to use it, but seem to have no choice. 

It's going to make things messy

Thank You

ORDER BY CASE cat_id WHEN 67 THEN 0 WHEN 65 THEN 1 WHEN 66 THEN 2 END

I'm just going to have to do a lot of php code to get an array to turn into the sql from bacon bits.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    name,
    cat_id 
    FROM table 
    WHERE cat_id IN (67)
    order by cat_id asc;
UNION
SELECT 
    name,
    cat_id 
    FROM table 
    WHERE cat_id IN (65,66)
    order by cat_id asc;
```